# Why is R printing 3 rows and 1 columns as the answer

Tags: r, matrix, cbind, poly

```
x <- data.frame(Level=c(6.5))
x_poly <- poly(x$Level, 4, raw=TRUE)
x1 <- cbind(x, x_poly[, 2:4])
```

This is my code and whenever I was using cbind for some reason it was printing 3 rows and column even though both x and x_poly have only 1 row.

```
x_poly <- as.data.frame(x_poly[, 2:4])
print(dim(x_poly))
```

I tried to print the dimensions of x_poly and x_poly[,2:4]. For some reason x_poly shows 1 row on;y but x_poly[2:4] shows 3 rows.

Comment: `x_poly[,2:4]` produces a 3-element named vector. (Try `dput(x_poly[,2:4])` so see an equivalent way to create the same vector.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extracting using `` `[` ``, R uses `drop` (see `?drop`), to coerce to the lowest possible dimensions.

So from the matrix,

```
> dim(x_poly)
[1] 1 4
```

you will get a vector.

```
> dim(x_poly[, 2:4])
NULL
```

We can do `drop=FALSE`.

```
> dim(x_poly[, 2:4, drop=FALSE])
[1] 1 3
```

Thus, what you're looking for is

```
> cbind(x, x_poly[, 2:4, drop=FALSE])
  Level     2       3        4
1   6.5 42.25 274.625 1785.062
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- data.frame(Level=c(6.5))
x_poly <- poly(x$Level, 4, raw=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was literally confused the entire time as to extracting columns was changing the matrix to a vector.

Comment: @TanishMajumdar good that you have learned it now; this is very often overlooked, also causes bugs in many packages